# Here Maps: Currently visible markers

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I have a HERE maps based javascript map on a website with a list of markers.
When the user zooms and pans the map, the `mapviewchangeend` event is triggered.

In that event, how can I find out which markers are currently visible?

The `H.Maps` object has a [`getObjectsWithin` method](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.25.0/api_reference/H.Map.html#getObjectsWithin), but that one needs a polygon - which I don't know how to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As polygon you should use the bounds from ViewModel's getLookAtData method:

```js
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', (e) => {
  let bounds = map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds;
  map.getObjectsWithin(bounds, (objects) => {
    console.log(objects);
  })
})
```

For more information check the [H.map.ViewModel.getObjectsWithin](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.ViewModel.html#getLookAtData) documentation.